# number equality to null using case when

Tags: postgresql

In my Postgres database, I'm checking user answers for correctness by checking if two IDs, "user_answered_id" and "expected_answer_id", are equivalent. If the user doesn't provide a "user_answered_id", then we still mark their answer as incorrect.

In Postgres, the following queries

`select case when 1 != null then TRUE else FALSE end as test;`

`select case when 1 = null then TRUE else FALSE end as test;`

both result in **FALSE**. This is true for any number check (e.g., `when 2 != null, when 3 != null, ...`, etc.

Why doesn't `CASE WHEN` show TRUE for `1 != null`?

Must I put in the check "or is null"? E.g.,

```
CASE WHEN 
  user_answered_id != expected_answer_id 
  OR user_answered_id IS NULL 
  THEN TRUE 
  ELSE FALSE 
END as user_incorrect_tally
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is: [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html)

```
select 2 is distinct from  null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t

select 2 is distinct from  1;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

From the docs:

> datatype IS DISTINCT FROM datatype → boolean
> Not equal, treating null as a comparable value.

> 1 IS DISTINCT FROM NULL → t (rather than NULL)

> NULL IS DISTINCT FROM NULL → f (rather than NULL)

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic): true, false, and ***null***. Null is not false. Null can be thought of as "no value".

Operations on null almost always yield null. So `1 != null` is null. `1 = null` is null. `null = null` is null. `5 < null` is null. Etc.

To check for null, [use `is null` and `is not null`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp).

---

Back to your query. [`is not distinct from` and `is distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) are like `=` and `!=` which treat null as a comparable value. So `null is distinct from 1` will be true.

```
select
  user_answered_id is distinct from expected_answer_id as user_incorrect
```

If you need to convert a null into a different value such as 0 or an empty string, use [`coalesce`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

```
select
  coalesce(user_answered_text, 'No Answer')
```

---

Your column is named "tally", but a tally means a count. If you intend to count a user's true and false answers use `count` with a `filter`.

```
select
  count(user_answered_id) filter (
    where user_answered_id = expected_answer_id
  ) as user_correct_tally,
  -- count ignores null, this will only be the questions they tried to answer
  count(user_answered_id) as user_answered_tally,
  count(user_answered_id) filter (
    where user_answered_is is distinct from expected_answer_id
  ) as user_incorrect_tally
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should check NULL value with `is null`, And last query you wrote is correct.

I suggest you to read below documents:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html